# DAL Generators for Java

Tags: java, data-access-layer

Are there any good data access layer generators for Java?  I have not used any and wondered what everyone recommends.  I basically want to create classes that access various tables in my SQL Server database.

Cheers,

Andez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java world, we mostly prefer O-R engine for persistence operations.. Hibernate is currently de-facto standart O-R engine. But I do prefer eclipselink...